# Creating a function in .net for login

Tags: c#, .net

I have salt and encrypted password in my db. and want to create a login function. I created a login function but it always returns false.

My function for conversion is here, is it right or not?

```
public static String HashPassword(String password, String salt)
{
    var combinedPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
    var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
    var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedPassword);
    var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}

public static Boolean ValidatePassword(String enteredPassword, String storedHash, String storedSalt)
{
    // Consider this function as an internal function where parameters like
    // storedHash and storedSalt are read from the database and then passed.

    var hash = HashPassword(enteredPassword, storedSalt);
    return String.Equals(storedHash, hash);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing ValidatePassword the right values?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to inspect the values in `storedHash` and `hash`? Do they look the same?

Comment: Are you sure you want to roll-your-own authentication? It's such an easy thing to get seriously wrong. It seems like a real time-waster to me given that the out-of-the-box authentication options in Asp.net have had some real brains solving this problem for quite a number of years. (Apologies if you're a "real brain").

Comment: do you have access to the code producing the hashes that where stored in your DB? Can you post this as well? (Your functions look fine to me - aside from not using `using` ;) )

Comment: I think your code (at least the code we can see) will be fine. I can see you've followed this article: http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/aspnet-web-security-protect-user-passwords-hashing-and-salt I have followed it myself in the past, it works. So I suggest your values are not as you're expecting.

Comment: probably you either flipped the salt/password, encode your result differently or use another hashing algorithm

Comment: I am passing right values..

Comment: storedSalt: TGZDjVrqg15/vqTufgxgzQ== storedHash: LrWFNIQYfUQ0ixcbIMj2ftXi5Ms= and my actual password is Password1!

Comment: @TimSchmelter, my function is returning false. So I am asking

Comment: @CarstenKönig, Can you suggest me, what method should I use, because I do not have code of registration, so don't know the method used while making registration.

Comment: @GoalDone Your salt appears to be base-64 encoded (the == is a giveaway, those are used as padding), so it's possible you need to decode it and append its bytes to the byte-encoded version of the password. As Carsten says, you need to know how the original hash was generated before you replicate it.

Comment: @GoalDone follow Adrians advice - you might have to try various combinations - if possible try to contact the guy(s) who implemented it, I'm sure they will help you out